# ReactJS - Make Click Event fire before onBlur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am implementing a custom input element similar to React Select. Users will be able to type something into the input element and select a suggestion from a dropdown (in my case, I implemented a component called SuggestionList which serves the same purpose as that dropdown suggestion list).

Currently, the SuggestionList is a sibling React component to the input element that the user types into (I named it CustomInput).

I want SuggestionList to disappear when CustomInput loses focus, so I implemented an onBlur handler which makes SuggestionList either un-mount or have "display" CSS property set to none. However, the problem is that after SuggestionList disappears, its onClick/handleClick event handler doesn't get called, and that event handler is responsible for adding user-selected elements to the selected items list.

Code shown below. There is more explaination after this code.

```
const AutocompleteInput = ({...}) => {
    const [suggestionVisible, setSuggestionVisible] = useState(true);

    return (
    ....
    <SystemComponent position="relative">
        <SuggestionList p={theme.space[4]} 
            position="absolute" 
            visible={suggestionVisible}
            value={value} 
            handleClick={handleSelect}
            ref={suggestionBox}
        />
        <CustomInput 
            variant="text" 
            placeholder={placeholder}
            value={value}
            onChange={(evt) => handleInputChange(evt.target.value)}
            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            onFocus={ () => {setSuggestionVisible(true)} }
            onBlur={ () => {setSuggestionVisible(false);} }
        />
    </SystemComponent>
    ....
    )

}
```

Therefore, when a user clicks something on the SuggestionList, my CustomInput immediately loses focus, causing SuggestionList to either be unmounted/disappear, and thus its event handler isn't called. As a result, the item the user selects isn't added to the suggestion list.

Having that said, I still want SuggestionList to disappear when the user clicks some other part of the website, thereby causing CustomInput to lose focus. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you are calling `onClickHandler()` inside your `onClick`. You can call this inside the `onBlur` on function.

For example

```
onBlur={ () => {onClickHandler(); setSuggestionVisible(false);} }
```